# How do you get the path of a jar in libgdx?

Tags: file, jar, path, directory, libgdx

I'm creating a desktop application in libgdx and want to get the jar path so I can access a folder next to it.  There's a lot of Gdx.files.(insert variable name here) but they are confusing me. Thank you!

Comment: Are the 2 answers the solution for your question? If so please mark it as solved. Thanks

Comment: @Springrbua Done, forgot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
FileHandle fh = Gdx.files.absolute(directory+"/foldername");
```

Then **fh** is the [FileHandle](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html) to your folder.

Answer (score 5):

The Gdx.files has a few different filehandles. Let me explain them:

1. Gdx.files.Claspath: Path relative to the root of the classpath. Readonly! Not for HTML5 and iOS
2. Gdx.files.Internal: Path relative to the asset (on Android) or root (on Desktop). Readonly!
3. Gdx.files.External: Path relativ to the SD Card (on Android) or Home (on Desktop). Not for HTML5
4. Gdx.files.Local: Path relative to private files (on Android) or Application root (on Desktop). Not for HTML5
5. Gdx.files.Absolute: A full Path. Not for HTML5.

Sources: [FileHandling](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling) and [Gdx.Files Source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Files.java)

Comment: I'm a little troubled here. You aren't answering the question, you answered after me. And you got more upvotes? ...

Comment: I got the same votes :P I hope this answer helps him. Your answer is absolutly correct, i just thought, that an explanation of all the GDX.files.xxx helps him. Maybe he decide to use another one, so he don't have to handle an absolute path.

Comment: No problem! If you think my answer is wrong feel free to downvote. It is absolutly okay. For me it is just important to know why you downvote so i am able to correct my answer.